# Why do we need to use awaitTermination but not just shutdownNow()?

Tags: java, thread-safety, executorservice

I am following the standard process that was recommended by oracle to shut down the executor services. here is the code that was recommended:

```
 void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
 }
```

I read through the descriptions for `shutdown()`, `awaitTermination`, and `shutdownNow()`;

I understand that
`shutdown()` only stop submitting new threads.

`awaitTermination` waits for the running threads to be shutdown. Returns a value if one of completed execution, time out or current thread interrupted.

`shutdownNow()` use `Thread.interrupt()` to interrupt threads.

My question is, if I know for sure that my threads only use `sleep` which can be interrupted by `Thread.interrupt()`. Is there still a value to call `awaitTermination` like what oracle recommended?

I know that `shutdownNow()` might have a chance to not shutdown a thread, but why can't we go ahead and do something like this to force stop the threads then see if there are still threads not stoped?

```
pool.shutdown();
pool.shutdownNow();
  try {
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   }
```

Comment: Ohhhhh!!!! Yes, you are right, so my code does do more than sleeping, it first sleep for a while then start doing other stuff. In that case, when my code is doing other stuff, if I don't use the awaitTermination, and if the other stuff is running very long time, it would not terminate immediately, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "standard process" just tries to handle the shutdown gracefully, the premise being not to interrupt the threads when it's not necessary.

First it stops accepting new task submissions and lets the ongoing tasks finish their work. It proceeds to forceful termination only when they don't finish within the grace period.

Comment: My purpose is to stop immediately when I call the `shutdownAndAwaitTermination()`. But from the recommendation, it still allows a grace time to finish the on going task. If I only want to stop now, would it still be necessary to call the first awaitTermination?

Comment: From a previous comment, I realized that my thread not only do a sleep but also have other process inside it, so if I fire shutdownNow when my thread is in the other process, it will not terminate correctly? right?

Comment: @MalcolmLiu Your shut-down approach is perfectly fine as far as you don't need this extra effort the documentation proposes. You need to inspect your use-case and decide if it's okay to skip it. Just bear in mind that there's a big chance your threads will be aborted once you call `shutdownNow` (`InterruptedException` will be thrown in those threads).

Comment: Thank you @jannis this really helped clearing the stuff up for me.